# Samsung Infuse - missing notifications after rooting

Tags: 2.3.3-gingerbread

i have a Samsung Infuse 4G and have rooted it.  Everything is great except i've somehow lost notifications  in the icons for Messaging, Gmail and Yahoo Mail.  I may  have deleted BadgeProvider.apk.  Would that cause the missing notifications?  I used NoBloat and backed up   all the apps i removed but I can't seem to get BadgeProvider back on. Thanks anyone for suggestions.

Comment: That's why it's recommended to [freeze](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/freeze-app/info) apps before removing them, so you can find out. Yes, that might be the cause; from the name, that's the one providing the "badges" on the icons, to show e.g. how many missed calls or pending short messages you've got.

Comment: It might be better to Titanum Backup your apps and reflash the ROM at this point. There's a lot of dependant tasks/apps and one falling down can just roll on like an avalanche.